# Test Data Generator CSV - Similar to Mockaroo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mocking, generator, export-to-csv

Trying to create my own test data generator something like http://www.mockaroo.com/, but I want to add more functionality, like combining sub strings between columns. From the website it looks like it was coded in ruby on rails. Should I try to do that? or on another language

Also is there any source code out there like mockaroo's I can use, just to modify functionality?

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: What languages do you know?  Without information, I recommend [LOLCODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOLCODE).  Rails is fine for this.

Comment: I'm familiar with Java, C++, HTML5, JS, SQL things like that. I wouldn't mind learning ruby, but if LOLCODE is better suited for a task like this, then I wouldn't mind looking into it

Comment: <grin> I think, hope?, the LOLCODE was meant to be funny?  It was to me at least...  </grin>  In any case, if you intend to write this as a website, in the tradition of Mockaroo, Rails is great.  If you intend to provide it as a submodule/subroutine, I'd probably go to a more portable language like C.  That's portable in that it can be more easily called as a library from many environments.

Comment: LOL for LOLCODE. Hahaha! This made my day. :))

Comment: For java,Checkout  https://github.com/android-Infoedge/randomizer.

Answer (score 1):

I just built this data generator https://retool.com/api-generator/ with json-server and Retool.

I also wanted more custom datatypes so this has a ton including a custom array builder. It then generates a REST API with read + write endpoints on top of a sample data set you define.

Feel free to use this or you can copy the app and edit it into your own data generator!

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using either Ruby on Rails with the 'faker' gem, or possibly Dancer (a modern light weight perl web framework) with perl's Data::Faker module, which is what inspired the faker gem.

Comment: Thatdude1 appears to want to write his own faker.  I think forgery is outstanding, myself.